# Python imaging library, ImageFont IOError

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

I have python-FotoBox-Script working perfectly well on my Ubuntu labtop, but on Raspberry-Pi running Raspbian the script is having the following problem:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/FotoBox $ python PythonCollage_31.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "PythonCollage_31.py", line 49, in <module>
        font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Comic_Sans_MS.ttf", 80, 0, 'unic')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 240, in truetype
        return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 137, in __init__
        self.font = core.getfont(font, size, index, encoding)
    IOError: unknown file format
```

I have also tried to create the font object using a other line of code:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Comic_Sans_MS.ttf", 80)
```

but with the same result.

The file with the font, for sure, exists!

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/FotoBox $ ls -l /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
insgesamt 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 128 Jun 17 22:04 Comic_Sans_MS.ttf
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax for ImageFont.truetype is this:

```
ImageFont.truetype(file, size, encoding=value)
```

So, if you add encoding= to the start of your forth parameter, use "" instead of '', and remove the third parameter, that should look like this:

```
ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Comic_Sans_MS.ttf", 80,
encoding="unic")
```

And this works for me.